# double hyphen in script makes firefox render strangely

Tags: html, firefox, comments, script-tag

```
<!-- <script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/  c-- ;//]]></script> -->
```

When I have the above line in the <head> section of a plain html page, Firefox 3.5.5 renders the trailing --> as text.  If I change c-- to c- it  doesn't.  Any ideas what's going on here?  I getting an artifact on my pages with this due to a very large script that's been crunched.  I can change the statement to c-=1 and avoid the problem for now but....  I'd like to know what bit/byte is biting my a$$.

Comment: Looks like this bug is relevant:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=477200

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to Firefox implementing SGML (on which HTML was based) comments strictly. This will only occur when the document is loaded in standards mode (i.e. there is a DOCTYPE).

The first `<!` starts a comment. The first `--` enters a section in which `>` characters are allowed. The second `--` (in your script) leaves the section in which `>` characters are allowed. The `>` at the end of `</script>` then ends the comment. The following `-->` is therefore no longer part of the the comment and gets rendered as text.

See http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/SGMLComments.html for a comprehensive guide to the issue.

Its also worth noting that the [HTML 4 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4) says that 'authors should avoid putting two or more adjacent hyphens inside comments' and the [HTML 5 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#comments) says comments must not 'contain two consecutive U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS characters (--)'.

The solution, as you've found, is to not include `--` in the middle of a comment.

Comment: It's probably not quite strictly SGML as it is implemented in Firefox, but even HTML5 disallows two consective hyphens in a comment: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#comments

Answer (score 1):

Technically you are not allowed to have double hyphen in a comment in HTML (or XML). So even if browsers "allow" if it is not valid and should fail an HTML validator.

See [Comment section of HTML 4 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4)

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this. Doesn't show up on 3.0.1.

Comment: This does happen Firefox 3.0.5, but only if there is a DOCTYPE present.